# Conditionally format first instance of value in column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to style the first instance of a value in a column. I found this custom formula through googling:

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$A100,$A1)=1
```

but this styles the *last* instance of the value, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this formula:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1
```

Comment: I am trying this, but it is hilighting the LAST instance of the given data, not the first. Any idea why?

I'm using `=COUNTIF($C1:$C1000,$C1)=1` with the range `C1:C1003` with rows 1 and 2 frozen.

Answer (score 2):

### THE COUNTIF SOLUTION:

The formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1` as suggested by Max is a common solution to this problem. It is a variation of the formula for finding duplicates : `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)>1`.

### COUNTIF DRAWBACK:

One of the drawbacks of using the `COUNTIF` formula is that it relies on the first parameter `$A$1:$A1` in order to accurately evaluate the conidtional-formatting correctly. The formula works the same in the conditional formatting as it would if you were to physically put the formula in B1, and the copy it down the whole column. The first copy in B1 will appear as the original formula `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1`but the one in B2 will appear as `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A2,$A2)=1`.

This can be a real problem and result in false positives or maybe the conditional formatting not working at all if you are doing any sorting, cutting and pasting, dragging and dropping rows or cells, etc.

### THE MATCH SOLUTION:

An improved version of this formula that eliminates the possibility of false positives and prevents the range from automatically being updated when it has been sorted, copied, cut, dragged, dropped, etc is as follows:

`=MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("$A:$A"),0)=ROW()`

### EXPLANATION OF MATCH SOLUTION:

The only purpose in the `INDIRECT` formula is to prevent the range from automatically updating. If you would prefer it to update when you copy and paste you can instead do: `=MATCH($A1,$A:$A,0)=ROW()` The key to this formula working properly is that the `MATCH` formula parameter 2 looks at the entire column, that way when it finds the exact location of parameter 1 it can compare it to the row#. If there are duplicates within column A Match will only return the location of the first instance. Since parameter 2 is the entire column the answer it returns is also the row# of the first instance. So the second part of the formula above `=ROW()` will compare the first instance's row# to the row# of the current cell, if they are identical than the formula will entire formula will return `TRUE`

### ADAPT MATCH SOLUTION TO FIND DUPLICATES (after first instance):

The `MATCH` formula can also be adapted to find all duplicates after the first entry. (basically the inverse) by changing the last part of the formula `=ROW()` into `<ROW()` So the duplicate finding formula would be: `=MATCH($A1,INDIRECT("$A:$A"),0)<ROW()`